# Zooming VideoView to fill the width, keeping aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-videoview

In my activity I need to show `VideoView` instance (full screen), with a button zooming the content - similar to iOS media player's one. I mean e.g. zooming 4:3 content to fill the screen width, keeping aspect ratio (thus effectively trimming top/bottom of the content).

I've just made a quick hack/experiment - `VideoView` inside a `AbsoluteLayout`, oversized so top/bottom is trimmed off. It works, but really feels like a hack.

Perhaps I'm blind, but is there no API to e.g. select video sub-rectangle to be displayed in the view?

Answer (score -4):

You can make the video use all width with this code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/myvideoid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </VideoView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Using match parent in the height will make your video preserve aspect ratio.
If what you want is to fill the screen just visit http://blog.kasenlam.com/2012/02/android-how-to-stretch-video-to-fill.html